# Frequency of letters in word

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x

So i've got algorithms question.
Suppose, we have a word, all letters in the word must be sorted by the frequency of their occurrence, starting with the most frequent.
E.g. "Suppose" will look like "ppSsuoe" or "Ssppoeu" and so on

I think that i should add word to list, find same letters, calculate how much same letters i have and append it to start of list, the letters that match only ones may printed as random.

But after appending word to list, i don't know what i should to do.
how to find same letters? how to sort them and append to start of word? Should i use temporary list? Or i should use key:value dictionary?

```
name = 'Suppose'
list = []
for letter in name:    
    list.append(letter)
```

Comment: Use a `Counter` from the collections module

Comment: i tried to use it but don't know hot to work with result of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `Collection`, followed by an appropriate sort:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> f = Counter("Suppose")
>>> ''.join(k*v for k,v in sorted(f.items(), reverse = True,key = lambda p:p[1]))
'ppuSseo'
```

Note however, that the final order of the letters with the same frequency is not specified by this method. Here, the only thing that is guaranteed is that more frequent letters will appear before less frequent. If you want e.g. letters of the same frequency to be themselves sorted alphabetically, you will need a different `key` argument.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

First, we convert our input into a dictionary, counting each item via `Counter`.  Next, we use `sorted` to sort the dictionary into the order we want (from greatest to least).  Finally, we loop over the dictionary, adding our items back into string form, so `p:2` turns into `pp`.  After that, we join all of our items together into a string via a `join`.

```
from collections import Counter

name = 'Suppose'
results = Counter(name)
print("".join([k * results[k] for k in sorted(results, key=lambda a: results[a], reverse = True)]))
```

Comment: know about that, but how print result as string like "ppSuseo", becoure result look like this Counter({'p': 2, 'u': 1, 'S': 1, 's': 1, 'o': 1, 'e': 1})

Comment: Updated my answer.  If you could mark as solution, it'd help a lot.

Comment: Thanks you a lot! but it code look like difficult for me, can you explain last line?

Comment: First, we convert our input into a dictionary, counting each item via `Counter`.  Next, we use `sorted` to sort the dictionary into the order we want (from greatest to least).  Finally, we loop over the dictionary, adding our items back into string form, so `p:2` turns into `pp`.  After that, we join all of our items together into a string via a `join`.

Answer (score 1):

```
from collections import OrderedDict
name = 'Suppose'
my_dictionary = dict()
for letter in name.lower():    
    if letter in my_dictionary.keys():
        my_dictionary[letter] += 1
    else:
        my_dictionary[letter] = 1
my_dictionary = OrderedDict(sorted(my_dictionary.items(), key=lambda x:x[1], reverse=True))

new_word = str()
for key, value in my_dictionary.items():
     new_word += (value*key)

print (new_word)
```

The way I would do it is first create a dict with key the letter and value the number of occurrences. Don't forget to use name.lower() in order to decapitalize the word first. Then, sort the dict by the values in descending order. Finally, create a new string and add to it the key*value

Answer (score 0):

```
string='suppose'
counts=[0]*26     #initialize a 26-sized array for each alphabet 
for letter in string:
 counts[ord(letter.lower())-97]+=1   #for each alphabet in the string update the count

greatest=0            #initialize largest count to 0 
for count in counts:    #look for each alphabet count  
 if count>greatest:greatest=count    #update the greatest count

while greatest:                                #while greatest doesn't equal to 0
 for i in range(len(counts)):                #look up all counts
  if counts[i]==greatest: print(end=chr(i+97)*greatest)    #the current alphabet has greatest count(as of yet) so print it 'greatest' times, the end is kept to skip newline
 greatest-=1                                   #update greatest count
print()                                 #newline feed
```